# webpack scss to css creating blank css file (vs 20017 .net core react)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core, sass

When I run my webpack task to create a css file from scss I end up with a blank css file.  I'm not sure if the config settings are wrong, or something else.

Background

I've set up a new test project in VS2017 .net core using the react template. This automatically created the webpack.config.js and webpack.config.vendor.js files for me.  Under the vendor config there was a setting for css which does the bootstrap css minimization.  I wanted to add a 3rd party scss (breakpoint-sass which is under node-modules) and do the same thing but scss to css and then min for prod. I've added in the config settings and used ExtractTextPlugin to extract it to a separate file (just to confirm it was working) but when I run the webpack I get a blank file. I've installed the sass loader.

Package.json (just in case its a version issue)

```
{
  "name": "CoreReactTest",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "4.0.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-less": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.2.1",
    "breakpoint-sass": "2.7.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.104",
    "lodash": "4.17.5"
  }
}
```

Webpack Vendor Config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
        allChunks: true,
        filename: 'vendor2.css'})
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.js', '.scss' ]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-
                loader?limit=100000' },
               { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract([isDevBuild ? 
               'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']) },
               {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    include: [/(src)/, /(node_modules)/],
                    exclude: /fonts/,
                    use: extractSass.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                }

            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: ['bootstrap', 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'event-source-polyfill', 'isomorphic-fetch', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', 'jquery', 'breakpoint-sass', 'breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]',
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            extractSass,
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), 
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDevBuild ? '"development"' : '"production"'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
};
```

I've added the extractSass const, scss test to rules, and 'breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss' to entry.  The _breakpoint.scss is the top level file, there are sub-folders and scss files that are required as well, so I'm not sure if this entry text is correct.

In my config it creates a vendor2.css file when I build the webpack but it is blank so not sure what I've done wrong? The css one runs and creates vendor.css when has all the bootstrap css in it.

Comment: Your webpack config looks fine. Are you importing the scss file somewhere in your code? The rules just tell webpack what to do with files you import, it won't import them for you.

Comment: Thanks @lukas-reineke I think it must be something like that. Glad my config looks good.  I've added import 'breakpoint-sass'; to my boot.tsx file but that hasn't helped. Maybe the wrong syntax or location?

Comment: sorry I didn't see that you had defined them as an entry point. This should be enough. You can try using a relative path from your webpack root directory. The import should work as well, but again use a relative path from the file you are in, and for sass you need to add the extension `import './breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss'`

Comment: Thanks @lukas-reineke.  I think I must be close (hopefully).  I created scss files for my project and now have these getting built out to css from my webpack.config.js.  The entry point for that uses the boot.tsx which uses "import style.scss" (style.scss then imports all the other scss files).  So I'm thinking its something not working with my entry in the vendor config.  I'm going to try susy scss and see if that works.

Comment: Please post a solution if you get one. This is also plaguing me!